# Apply Auto Smooth and its angles in a script

Tags: scripting, import

I am modifying an Import OBJ script. I want it to make all objects smooth, with Auto Smooth turned on, and with an auto_smooth_angle of 30º.

My edit is as follows: after

`for mesh in new_objects:`
I have added

`bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()` and it works as expected, but

`bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth=1` fails me. Any thoughts?

Just do clarify: I want this:

[image]

to become this:

[image]

Comment: how does it fail ?

Comment: " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use something like this which first selects all the objects that you have listed in 'new_objects', and sets autosmooth to 1 on them, then once they're all selected it sets smooth shading on all of them

```
import bpy
import math

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select = False  # safe to un-select first, all objects.

    ''' if you have a 'new_objects' list , then skip objects not on the list: '''
    # if not (obj in new_objects): continue

    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.select = True 
        obj.data.use_auto_smooth = 1
        obj.data.auto_smooth_angle = math.pi/4  # 45 degrees
        # ob.data.auto_smooth_angle = math.radians(40)  # 40 degrees as radians

bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

Comment: That worked [virtually] out of the box. Perfect, thanks, @zeffii. [virtually] explained: I had to comment out the `import bpy` and `import math` lines, because it was giving me an error, and I already had those imports in he beginning of the code.

Comment: is it possible to do this without bpy.ops and/or without having to select the object?