# Autosmooth checkbox not being checked

Tags: scripting

I had a small autosmooth script based on [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36248/82533) by user @zeffii

And recently updated to blender 3.4 alpha and somehow the checkbox is not being checked when running the script. Here is the script:

```
import bpy
import math

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

for ob in selected_objects:
    ob.select_set(True)
    ob.data.use_auto_smooth = True 
#        ob.data.use_auto_smooth = 1
    ob.data.auto_smooth_angle = math.radians(60)  # 40 degrees as radians

bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

"use_auto_smooth" part is not working. The checkbox is not being check but the angle is updated. Not sure if its a bug or a mistake in the code?

Also, I used to use 1 but saw that True is now the correct way. Or are both correct to use?

Comment: Hello ! As a heads-up we don't really encourage questions and answers about alpha or beta versions. Usually most of the problems are solved at the official release date either by being fixed if they come from a bug, or by being included in the release notes if they come from a breaking change in the API. In this case it's the call to `bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()` that unticks the checkbox. Call it before your `for` loop. (It was the same in realier versions)

Comment: And using `True` instead of `1` is more semantically correct because the property is representing a boolean value, although I don't think there is any impact code-wise, `1` is cast to a boolean value automatically. It might have been the only way to set this property in the past.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, the change was introduced in 3.3 which is a released version. :) Writing an answer right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Blender 3.3 [bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=shade_smooth#bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth) takes `use_auto_smooth` as an argument. By default it is set to `False`, which means if you don't explicitely add the argument as `True` it will set `data.use_auto_smooth` to `False`.

The good thing is that it renders the `for` loop useless.

```
import bpy
import math


bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth(use_auto_smooth=True, auto_smooth_angle=math.radians(40))
```

Or if you don't want to rely on having to select the objects in the interface, use an [Operator Override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) :

```
import bpy
import math

objects_to_smooth = [
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"],
    bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"],
    bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"],
    # etc.
]

with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_editable_objects=objects_to_smooth):
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth(use_auto_smooth=True, auto_smooth_angle=math.radians(40))
```

By the way there is now an operator to do exactly what this script does in the interface. Search for "Shade Auto Smooth".

[image]

Comment: Sorry you are right about the alpha version, ill keep that in mind next time. Thanks for the quick and detailed answer, it works perfectly. :)